# Logging a user session for playback

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-2

Running an MVC2 site against IIS7 and would like to capture more detail of how users traverse the site - ideally to the point of being able to replay even the duration between mouse clicks - feedback of where people pause and/or backtrack.

I could do this with flash but that's no longer an option. Now it's just IIS7 via asp.net f4. IIS7 _should be able to provide this via 3rd party extensions - especially for this sort of niche need. I'm willing to consider client-side .net components but this sure seems to be the responsibility of the server.

[opps...does this belong on serverfault?]

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the "in-house" solution you're after but we are about to implement [SessionCam](http://www.sessioncam.com/) at my company, which seems like a pretty good match for what you're looking for. Not having actually finished implementing it yet, I can't vouch for it in terms of quality at this point - but the description of the product certainly matches.

You aren't going to be able to capture the level of detail you need using a solely server-side solution. There needs to be a degree of client-side work - whether it's in flash or javascript - to capture things such as where the mouse is hovering (for heatmaps etc).

Comment: At risk of repeating myself - still seems strange this use case doesn't have more solution providers but thanks for the time.

Answer (score 2):

justSteve. Here is a solution that we have used:

- http://www.seevolution.com/

I don't think that it gives time between clicks, but it does give very detailed tracking considering it's price (I don't know if that's an issue). We have *really* liked it. Fantastic detail.

You could also roll your own solution. Using jQuery and the `$(document).click()` function, you can log when they click, and the points on the screen. Then every couple of minutes, serialize it and fire it off to the server. You can get extremely fine-grained detail that way. The nice thing with seevolution is that they've done all of the work for you already, but it probably isn't as detailed as you would like.

JMax

Answer (score 1):

I personally haven't used this product, but a friend of mine spoke highly of it.

[Clicktale](http://www.clicktale.com/)

Comment: Appreciate you passing that along...still can't believe the lack of apps that address this need.